# How to open a file/protocol with a specific (not default) class

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, shellexecute

There are several questions on StackOverflow along the lines of "How do I use ShellExecute/ShellExecuteEx in C#?", to which the answer is pretty much: "Use System.Diagnostics.Process".  However, what I want to do is open a file or URL using a *non* default handler.

I can accomplish this using ShellExecuteEx by just passing in the class name and setting the [SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and I have this working using DllImport.

What I want to know is: is there a way of doing this in C# without importing from the DLL?  Is there a way of passing this kind of information to Process, or is the way I have it working the "right" way of doing it?

Comment: Please keep stuff like " (C# / .NET)" out of your titles, and into the tags.

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent way of doing it in .NET. Your way of handling (using ShellExecuteEx) it is right way.

Comment: Is this definite: there really is no way of doing it in .NET code?